# Bash: Start and kill child process

Tags: bash, process, sleep

I have a program I want to start. Let' say this program will run a while(true)-loop (so it does not terminate. I want to write a bash script which:

1. Starts the program (`./endlessloop &`)
2. Waits 1 second  (`sleep 1`)
3. Kills the program --> How?

I cannot use $! to get pid from child because server is running a lot of instances concurrently.

Comment: What code have you tried and how has it failed you?

Comment: I tried the two things in the brackets above. The problem is: how to kill endlessloop?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Store the PID:

```
./endlessloop & endlessloop_pid=$!
sleep 1
kill "$endlessloop_pid"
```

You can also check whether the process is still running with `kill -0`:

```
if kill -0 "$endlessloop_pid"; then
  echo "Endlessloop is still running"
fi
```

...and storing the content in a variable means it scales to multiple processes:

```
endlessloop_pids=( )                       # initialize an empty array to store PIDs
./endlessloop & endlessloop_pids+=( "$!" ) # start one in background and store its PID
./endlessloop & endlessloop_pids+=( "$!" ) # start another and store its PID also
kill "${endlessloop_pids[@]}"              # kill both endlessloop instances started above
```

See also [BashFAQ #68](http://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashFAQ/068), "How do I run a command, and have it abort (timeout) after N seconds?"

The [ProcessManagement](http://mywiki.wooledge.org/ProcessManagement) page on the Wooledge wiki also discusses relevant best practices.

Comment: @今天春天, this answer does that. `$endlessloop_pid` stores the PID of only the one that was started, or in the `endlessloop_pids` array case, of the two that were started.

Comment: The point is that I cannot distinguish which one is the correct one to kill.

Comment: @今天春天 Then who can? If you are starting more than one process, there must be *some* distinguishing feature that leads you to want to kill one but not the other. Do you want to kill the one that started first? Is there something about what a particular process did that leads you to kill it? You aren't giving enough detail to provide a reasonable answer.

Comment: I want to kill exactly that process I startet.

Comment: @今天春天, that is exactly what this answer does. Why do you think it does anything else?

Answer (score 0):

You can use the pgrep command for the same:

```
kill $(pgrep endlessloop)
```

Comment: Use `pkill` and call it a day!!

Comment: That'll kill *every* endlessloop, not just the one you started. It'll also kill `endlessloopctl`, or `read-endlessloop-logs`.

Comment: I cannot wait a second here?